# KIF + Swift reset/restart app

Tags: swift, automated-tests, kif

I'm developing automated tests using KIF and Swift
I wrote some tests but they don't depend on each other 
How to reset app and execute this in beforeEach() method?

```
class PassengerCountTests: KIFTestCase {

enum Element: String {
    case passengerCount = "passengerCount_label"
    case plusButton = "plus_button"
    case minusButton = "minus_button"

}

func getElement(element: Element) -> UIView {
    return tester().waitForView(withAccessibilityLabel: element.rawValue)
}

func tap(element: Element) {
    tester().tapView(withAccessibilityLabel: element.rawValue)
}


func testMinPassengerNumber() {
    let passengerCount = getElement(element: Element.passengerCount)
    let minusButton = getElement(element: Element.minusButton)

    XCTAssertEqual(passengerCount.accessibilityValue, "1")
    XCTAssertEqual(minusButton.isProbablyTappable, false)
}

func testMaxPassengerNumber() {
    for _ in 1...4 {
        tap(element: Element.plusButton)
    }

    let passengerCount = getElement(element: Element.passengerCount)
    let plusButton = getElement(element: Element.plusButton)

    XCTAssertEqual(passengerCount.accessibilityValue, "5")
    XCTAssertEqual(plusButton.isProbablyTappable, false)
}
```

}

Comment: I feel like you need to rethink your testing strategy. Tests aren't supposed to be dependant on running order.

Comment: now I noticed what I wrote.. :/ of course tests should not depend on each other and I wrote my tests according to that.... each test starts from the same  point and I want to find way to reset app

Comment: Regardless, tests aren't supposed to be dependant on running order. Could you give us a little more information on what exactly you are trying to achieve in these tests and what is forcing you to need to restart the app?
If you stop the app, you stop your tests. The only way to achieve what you're asking is to program your app to reset back to initial state. The better way would be to look at other ways to allow these tests to pass.

Comment: i.e. scenario1: open app, change counter, send form and check results; scenario2: open app, set different value to counter, send form and check results - so yes, I have to find a way to back app to initial state, but how ;)

Comment: So the tests are only different in that they set the counter to a different value?

Comment: in this case yes, first I'm checking min value, second max value but when second test is trying to run app is on result page and I have to reset/restart/back to initial state

Comment: And the test itself is performing a network request? What defines whether or not the test should pass?

Comment: it was only an example, i want to perform other tests which starts from the same point - so it is the issue :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code from these tests.